# Elasticsearch not assigning all shards on reboot

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding, multiple-instances

I have a single ES AWS instance that I've been logging to as part of a standard ELK stack.  It has been running for about 4 weeks.  I had replication disabled.

Today, I decided to stop and start the instance so that I could increase the memory size of the it.  When it came back up, only about half of the 5 shards for each index were assigned...in some cases two, and in some cases 3.

After fooling around a bunch, I looked on the disk, where I found that each of my indexes were stored within two high-level directories, '/data1/elasticsearch/es-vpc3/nodes/0' and /data1/elasticsearch/es-vpc3/nodes/1'.  It is the shards stored in the '0' directory that were being assigned.  The shards stored in '1' were not. This indicated to me that I must have been running two ES instances on the one instance without knowing it.  So I figured, 'what the heck', and I started a second copy of ES.  Sure enough, my other shards were assigned to the second instance!

Here's the problem though.  I've been using the HEAD plugin to view my cluster.  Prior to the reboot, the display represented the cluster as a single ES instance with all of the shards being shown together in a single row.  Now, I get two rows, one for each instance of ES, with the appropriate nodes for what I saw in the directory structure shown in each of the two rows.  So something is clearly different than it was before. It appears that I was not running two distinct instances of ES.  So what was I doing?  Why did my indexes get split across two "nodes/N" directories and why upon reboot did only the "nodes/0" shards get assigned?

Can someone tell me what is going on here....what was different about my setup before and after the reboot?

TIA for any enlightenment.

Comment: can you run curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty' and post the result?